# list indices must be integers not str

Tags: python

```
import os
def search_dir(dir,topdown=True):
    files = {}
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir, topdown):
        for name in files:
            fileAdd = os.path.join(root,name)
            fileSize = os.path.getsize(fileAdd)
            files[fileAdd] = str(fileSize);
            print (fileAdd + ', Size:' + str(fileSize)+'kb')
        for name in dirs:
            fileAdd = os.path.join(root,name)
            fileSize = os.path.getsize(fileAdd)
            files[fileAdd] = fileSize;
            print (fileAdd + ', Size:'+ str(fileSize)+'kb')

dir = raw_input('please input the path:')
search_dir(dir)

for fileAdd in sorted(files):
    print("{0} size {1}kb".format(fileAdd, files[fileAdd]))
```

The terminal says "list indices must be integers not str" and I do not know why?

Answer (score 2):

You used the 'files' variable twice.

```
files = {}
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir, topdown):
```

One of them has got to go.

(Rant mode: ON)

This sort of thing is very easily found when using a debugger.

(Rant mode: OFF)

Comment: StackOverflow *is* a kind of distributed debugger. And I bet that it is often faster than using a real debugger... ;)

Comment: @Bitwise - Hmmm, I kinda like that thought.